# Date from String in Objective C with weekday

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert a string to date, my string is **Sunday, November 24, 2020 @ 5:00 PM** and is of date format **EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY @ hh:mm a**

I am writing below code for the same but date is returning nil with this format and date. When I am removing Day and EEEE from format, it is working fine.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSLocale * locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_LU"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY @ hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Sunday, November 24, 2020 @ 5:00 PM"]];
//This line returning nil and assigning into date object
NSString * dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the year specifier is wrong, it must be `yyyy` but this is irrelevant with regard to the issue. And Nov 24 2020 is **Tuesday** by the way (also irrelevant).

In German (not even in luxembourgian German) there is no `Sunday` or `Tuesday`, for the input string you have to set the locale to something in English for example generic `en_US_POSIX`

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy @ hh:mm a";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Tuesday, November 24, 2020 @ 5:00 PM"]];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"de_LU"];
NSString * dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```